# firefox - Logging certain parts of a page

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, logging, extract, html

Ok here is what i though would be awesome to have:
Firefox to log all `<code>` tags in a file so that emacs can find autocompletions from there.
This should be done without asking permission or bothering the user otherwise. Also, lazy as I am, if creating an entire extension for that can be avoided i would embrace that.
Any ideas on how that can happen or if something like that already exists(like an extension) to get ideas from?

Comment: FWIW, the description of the idea makes very little sense.

Comment: i find it is quite simple and straightforward: the desired behavior is that whenever ff renders a `<code>` html tag it writes the contents in a file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do automatic writes to file without an extension. This shouldn't be too hard to write in the Addon SDK: use [page-mod](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) to get notified of new pages, [pass the data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/using-port.html) you want to save to the main add-on, then use the internal [file module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/packages/api-utils/docs/file.html#open%28path%2C%20mode%29) to write the data.